# Translating String From ASCII to IBM037 Java Vs Csharp

Tags: java, c#, character-encoding, ascii, ebcdic

I am trying to convert A simple Ascii String to EBCIDIC , however i am noticing differences between java C# byte values. Below is C# and java sample code. I have tried several Chars and i see wide difference on each language Byte code

```
 using System;
 using System.Text;

 public class Program {
   public static void Main(){
     string s = "B";
     Encoding ebcdic = Encoding.GetEncoding(37);//IBM037 encoding
     byte[] asciiBt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
     byte[] ebcdicBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, ebcdic, asciiBt);

 foreach(byte b in ebcdicBytes) {
   Console.WriteLine(b);//194 is written to console
 };   } }
```

On comparing with similar java Code

```
public class Example{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
  String s = "B";
  byte arr[] = s.getBytes("IBM037");
  for (byte x: arr){
     System.out.println(x);//-62 to console
  }}}
```

Can some one Guide me why the same Charset in 2 different Languages is Writing Different byte Value

Comment: `byte` in Java is signed, the equivalent of `sbyte` in C#.  `(byte)194` and `(sbyte)(-62)` are both `0xc2`.

Comment: `System.out.printf("0x%02x%n",x);` would be a better way of visualization

Comment: Hi @madreflection If a file written by c# for example writes it as 194 (byte code in the file) and java program reading file (when trying to read byte 194) will it not mismatch ?

Comment: The bit pattern is the same, and that's what matters.

Comment: If Java is reading the byte, it will see it as `-62`, because that's what `0xc2` is in Java's `byte` data type.